# getting taxcode of the order from Prestashop webservice

Tags: prestashop

I am fetching the orders of the Prestashop site using webservices. I am getting all the details except the taxcode associated with the order. Please suggest from where I will be able to get that data.

I am seeing a data  **19.600**  in the data XML wht is this?
Please help.

Thanks

Utpal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in prestashop 1.5 when you parse an order . get `id_order_detail` and request web service with this ID to get `tax_name` , `tax_rate` etc.

Comment: Hi,I have checked your solution and it is working but in some order though tax havebeen associated it is not coming with order_details webservice. Please tell if I have to do anything extra to make this work.Please reply .